# Делает ли SELECT FOR UPDATE в PostgreSQL копирование записи в блоке данных?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Известно, что PostgreSQL внутренне не обновляет записи -- при обновлении какой-либо записи просто предыдущая версия помечается устаревшей и в блок данных добавляется копия этой записи. При этом записей в блоке ограничено размером этого блока, а старые записи удаляются только VACUUM-ом. Если блок переполняется, то нужно писать в новый, а это потеря производительности, и/или еще какие-то минусы.

Теперь предположим, что у нас есть большая таблица (сотня полей), при этом в ней активно обновляются (с каждым бизнес-запросом) только десяток полей, а остальные -- это в сущности всякие подстроечные параметры. Например, в таблице есть поле со временем последнего запроса из внешней системы.

Архитектура PostgreSQL приведет к тому, что на каждую транзакцию обновления будет копироваться 90% не меняющихся полей в таблице ради того, чтобы записать оставшиеся 10%. Это приведет к быстрому распуханию файлов данных.

Таким образом, принято решение разделить таблицу на две, с часто и с редко меняющимися данными. И тут возникает вопрос.

Приложение в своей работе использует `SELECT FOR UPDATE` на этой таблице, чтобы бизнес-запросы сериализовались в правильном порядке. Когда мы разделим таблицу на две, то `SELECT FOR UPDATE` будет делаться только для одной из таблиц (это делает ORM, на который не повлиять, вторая таблица все равно не будет использоваться без первой), и тут возникает вопрос, а чем является этот `SELECT FOR UPDATE`? Является ли он той записью (write), которая приводит к дублированию записи (row/record) в файлах данных или нет?

Документация для [SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) направляет на [документацию по блокировкам](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS), где сказано следующее

> PostgreSQL doesn't remember any information about modified rows in memory, so there is no limit on the number of rows locked at one time. However, locking a row might cause a disk write, e.g., `SELECT FOR UPDATE` **modifies selected rows** to mark them locked, and so will result in disk writes.

Означает ли выделенное то самое копирование строчки (row/record) в блоке данных? Иными словами, ради того, чтобы разделение большой таблицы имело задуманный смысл, нужно ли делать `SELECT FOR UPDATE` для таблицы с меньшим числом полей (оперативные данные), или такая оптимизация также сработает, если будет делаться для таблицы с большим числом полей (настроечные данные)?

Comment: весьма смахивает на «[ошибку xy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)». и корень проблемы где-то в районе архитектуры, конкретнее — похоже на плохую [нормализацию данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: Может быть. Но что есть, то есть, система работает и ее нужно обновлять, без простоев

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `select for update` производит модификацию данных страницы, содержащей эту строку
- `select for update` *не* записывает новую копию строки = не приводит к раздуванию таблицы

Оба утверждения верны.

И отсюда нужно пояснять, как именно работает блокировка строки на уровне реализации. Общий обзор приведён в [`src/backend/access/heap/README.tuplock`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_STABLE/src/backend/access/heap/README.tuplock), я процитирую только самое необходимое:

> is implemented by storing locking information in the tuple header: a
> tuple is marked as locked by setting the current transaction's XID as
> its XMAX, and setting additional infomask bits to distinguish this
> case from the more normal case of having deleted the tuple

во время захвата блокировки на конкретную строку, мы выставляем в заголовке этой строки значение XMAX и некоторые дополнительные биты, помогающие отличать между собой разные состояния этой строки.

Во время этого процесса мы меняем заголовок страницы именно там где строка расположена на странице данных - это обычная запись данных, страничка "пачкается", пишется на диск и так далее.

но FOR UPDATE не помечает эту строку удалённой и не создаёт копию строки в новом месте таблицы, в этом нет нужды.

Comment: Благодарю, то, что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` в PostgreSQL блокирует выбранные строки для изменения другими транзакциями до завершения текущей транзакции. Он не копирует записи в блоке данных.

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` блокирует выбранные строки с помощью механизма блокировки строк в PostgreSQL. Это означает, что другие транзакции не смогут изменять заблокированные строки до тех пор, пока текущая транзакция не завершится.

Таким образом, `SELECT FOR UPDATE` не создает никаких дополнительных копий записей в блоке данных. Он просто блокирует выбранные строки для изменения другими транзакциями до завершения текущей транзакции.

Comment: А ссылки на документацию / описание, что делается во время `SELECT FOR UPDATE` не найдется?

Comment: @Mingun, даже прямо на этом же сервере есть подробное изложение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1064951/178576

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Это изложение для пользователей, оно не объясняет, что там делается внутри и в частности, никак не проясняет мой вопрос